# Chrome extension: How to open a link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

In my Stackoverflow folder, I have `stackoverflow.ico` and 2 bellow files. When importing it to Chrome, it shows the icon in address bar, but when I click on it, Chrome doesn't open any new tab. What am I doing wrong?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Stackoverflow",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "stackoverflow.ico"
  },
  "background":
  {
    "page": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
      {
        var newURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The problem is that you are violating [manifest version 2's `content security policy`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html). To fix it all you have to do is get rid of inline script, in this case your background `page`. Turn it into a background `script` like this:

**manifest.json**

```css
"background":{
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  var newURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

If, for some reason, you do need it to be a page, then simply include the script as an external file and declare it as a page like before.

Comment: how can i send the newURL from popup.js ?

Comment: This is working fine.. but opening multiple tabs with subsequent clicks. Any tips?

Answer (score 35):

In my case I needed to open link in a new tab when I clicked a link within extension popup window, it worked fine with `target` attribute set to `_blank`:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Comment: Well, this will open new tab in a browser, but it will close the popup (what is not always desired).

Answer (score 7):

I would prefer [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29543453/6045507) - just add action to onclick

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).prop('href'), active: false});
    return false;
});
```

This will open all links (even links that were dynamically created) that have target="_blank" attribute **in a new tab without loosing popup focus.**

Comment: where do you call this one? i mean is it written under content.js or background.js?

Comment: it's written in content.js

Answer (score 4):

You do not need jQuery. Just use `window.open("http://example.com", "_blank")`.