# Creating a Chrome Extension that has button links to websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've written code for an extension that should launch given websites and the HTML file when launched works properly; however, when I click on the extension, the buttons do not do anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Apps Launcher</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Apps Launcher</h1>
<FORM>
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Gmail" Onclick="window.location.href='https://www.gmail.com'"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Drive" Onclick="window.location.href='https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/'"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Calendar" Onclick="window.location.href='https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7'"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Docs" Onclick="window.location.href='https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/'"> 
<FORM/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would you recommend I do it?

Answer (score 3):

First off, please learn how to help yourself by learning [how to debug extension popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). It involves right-clicking the button and selecting *Inspect popup*.

If you do that, the first thing you'll see is something along those lines:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

That's because Chrome's restrictive [Content Security Policy for extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) doesn't allow setting click handlers with a string of text in the HTML itself. See [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working) for more information.

Furtherfore, what do your handlers try to achieve? If you click on this in a popup window, `window` refers to the popup itself. I doubt you want to load said sites *in the popup itself*, you probably want to open a new tab instead. I don't think you can navigate the popup window itself to an external website.

You are presented with a choice in fixing this:

1. The path of least resistance is to use pure HTML links instead of JS:

   ```
   <a href="https://www.gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
   ```

   You could then style this `<a>` element as you wish - it can *look* like a button.
2. If you specifically want `<input type="button">` elements, you need to follow the standard procedure using `addEventListener` for `"click"` events in your `popup.js`. See CSP documentation and the `onClick` question linked above - as well as code in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263031/934239).

   You'll want to use `chrome.tabs.create` instead to open links in new tabs, for example:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://gmail.com"});
   ```

   See also this question: [Open new tab without losing popup focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29542742/934239).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up event listeners. Something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('INPUT[Type="BUTTON"]').forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    window.location.href = event.target.dataset.location
  })
)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Apps Launcher</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Apps Launcher</h1>
<FORM>
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Gmail" data-location="https://www.gmail.com"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Drive" data-location="https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Calendar" data-location="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7"> 
    <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Google Docs" data-location="https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/"> 
<FORM/>

<!-- insert script file, with content from JavaScript section -->
      
</body>
</html>
```

Your code smells for me. Consider these sections from Google Style Guide:

- [Capitalization](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Capitalization#Capitalization)
- [Intendation](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=General_Formatting#General_Formatting)
- [Use `a` tag instead of javascript for navigation](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Semantics#Semantics)

Comment: These may be basic questions, but where would that "document.query..." section go? In the Manifest? And wouldn't any JavaScript need to go in the background.js file?

Comment: Append it to `popup.js` and move `<script src="popup.js"></script>` to the bottom of the page