# Simple Chrome Extension : Open an url in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to create a "new tab" extension like [Panda](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panda-hacker-news-dribbbl/jhiocdmmaannaccoofjfmjpbfkogmnap) or the [Product Hunt Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/product-hunt/likjafohlgffamccflcidmedfongmkee): the user can open a new tab with my website inside, with an hidden url.

I've generated my package with the awesome [Extensionizr](http://extensionizr.com/) and here is my `manifest.json` :

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My awesome app",
  "homepage_url": "http://myapp.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://myapp.com/*"
  ]
}
```

My `background.js` come from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503879/chrome-extension-open-link-in-new-tab), the problem seems really similar.

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
  var newURL = "http://myapp.com";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

I'm still getting this error when I try to run the background page from the extension settings : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined`

And when I open a new tab, Google Chrome took the advantage and display me a google search page.

I do it wrong, and I don't know how/where/why

Comment: Where's your `"browser_action"` field in the manifest?

Comment: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` is fired when a browser action icon is clicked rather than opening a new tab in other ways. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely off-track. You don't want to open a (simple) new tab, you want to replace the "New Tab page".
[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30947933/934239) correctly explains why your code does not work, but it won't do what you wanted.

To replace Chrome's New Tab page, you need to use [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override):

```
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "myPage.html"
  },
```

Inside that `myPage.html`, you can add an `<iframe>` for your remote content.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to register the browser action in the manifest. Here is your manifest with the browser action added at the bottom.

```
{
  "name": "My app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My awesome app",
  "homepage_url": "http://myapp.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://myapp.com/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {}
}
```

Here are the browser action docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

Comment: That's.. Not what the user is looking for. What he needs is a new tab override. Read the question carefully.